# Percentage calculation between two values

Tags: java, android, math

I want to obtain a result between 0.0 and -0.5. I have the values: MIN = x, MAX = y and IN = x. The value MIN should result in a percent of -0.5% and MAX 0.0%. For example, if the value of MIN is 240px, the MAX is 600px and the IN is 360px the IN should result a percent of -0.33%. But I don't know how to do this calculation.

P.S.: the IN can't be higher than 0.0 or lower than -0.5.
P.S.2: sorry about my english.

The code I tried, but didn't work:

```
float percent = (((currentX / max) * min) / (max - min) * (-1)); Animation openNavigationDrawer = new TranslateAnimation( Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, percent, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f); openNavigationDrawer.setDuration(200); navigationDrawer.setAnimation(openNavigationDrawer);
```

And the second one (worked, but was not good):

```
float percent = -0.0f;
    float posDividerDefault = max / 12, 
    posDividerOne = min + posDividerDefault, posDividerTwo = posDividerOne + posDividerDefault, 
    posDividerThree = posDividerTwo + posDividerDefault, posDividerFour = posDividerThree + posDividerDefault, 
    posDividerFive = posDividerFour + posDividerDefault, posDividerSix = posDividerFive + posDividerDefault;

    if (currentX < posDividerOne) {
        percent = -0.5f;

    } else if (currentX > posDividerOne && currentX < posDividerTwo) {
        percent = -0.45f;

    } else if (currentX > posDividerTwo && currentX < posDividerThree) {
        percent = -0.4f;

    } else if (currentX > posDividerThree && currentX < posDividerFour) {
        percent = -0.3f;

    } else if (currentX > posDividerFour && currentX < posDividerFive) {
        percent = -0.2f;

    } else if (currentX > posDividerFive && currentX < posDividerSix) {
        percent = -0.1f;

    } else if (currentX > posDividerSix) {
        percent = -0.0f;

    }
```

Comment: A better explanation of the calculation would certainly help.

Comment: You should tell us what you're trying to achieve. Maybe you don't even need this calculation.

Comment: very wiered calculation... why you need it

Comment: I would say that 360 is 33 1/3% of between 240 and 600. I don't understand the negative percentages. Do you mean that 240 is -50% of between 360 and 600?

Comment: I need a negative percentage to create an animation. The TranslateAnimation in Android. The result should be between 0 (float) and -0.5.

Comment: Why should IN result in a percent of -0.25%? You didn't explain that part of the calculation very well.

Comment: The code I tried was this: 

float percent = (((currentX / max) * min) / (max - min) * (-1));
Animation openNavigationDrawer = new TranslateAnimation(
    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, percent,
    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f);
  openNavigationDrawer.setDuration(200);
  navigationDrawer.setAnimation(openNavigationDrawer);

But it didn't work. Then I did this code below, but it was not so "smooth":

Comment: float percent = -0.0f;
  float posDividerDefault = max / 12, 
  posDividerOne = min + posDividerDefault, posDividerTwo = posDividerOne + posDividerDefault, 
  posDividerThree = posDividerTwo + posDividerDefault, posDividerFour = posDividerThree + posDividerDefault, 
  posDividerFive = posDividerFour + posDividerDefault, posDividerSix = posDividerFive + posDividerDefault;
  
  if (currentX < posDividerOne) {
   percent = -0.5f;
   
  } else if (currentX > posDividerOne && currentX < posDividerTwo) {
   percent = -0.45f;

Comment: hell just edit the question, do you think people will hunt code in the comments?

Comment: Let's suppose that 0 is 100% and -0.5 is 0%. I need to get a "normal" percentage, but it must be converted between those values.

Comment: This question certainly doesn' t belong to here..

Comment: Use @MightyPork's answer that is correct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what you described, I guess the formula you want is this:

```
result = -0.5 + 0.5*( (in - min) / (max - min) );
```

But since you didn't show any code nor explained it's purpose, it's just a wild guess.

Comment: I agree it seems like the user is looking for -0.33333 not -0.25

Comment: Yes, it worked perfectly. Thank you very much! Sorry about the wrong question, I'll edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly the same as @MightyPork but IMHO demonstrates a little clearer what is happening:

```
static final double MIN = -0.5;
static final double MAX = 0.0;
public void test(double x, double min, double max) {
  // (x - min)     = translate to min
  // / (max - min) = scale to unit
  // * (MAX - MIN) = scale to final
  // + MIN         = translate to MIN
  double v = (x - min) / (max - min) * (MAX - MIN) + MIN;
  System.out.println("test("+x+","+min+","+max+") = "+v);
}
```

Comment: `a little clearer` oh come on, your code is one big mess. it's just plain silly to name the bounds MIN MAX if your arguments are min and max - and you don't need to make them fields at all, if they're used just here, why not hardcode them.